# gitolite permissoins with branches and folders

Tags: git, gitolite

In gitolite I want the `@developers` to be able to push to any branch except for `master`.
I want `user1` to be able to push to any branch (including `master`) except not a certain directory on `master`.

How would I do that?

Comment: @VonC helped my try a few things, but we came to the conclusion that we would have to create a custom VREF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should address both:

```
repo arepo
  RW          = @developer
  -  master$  = @developer

  RW                     = user1
  - master and VREF/NAME/adirectory = user1
```

The [access rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html) and [refex](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/refex.html) pages explain how /refs/head/master branch is denied for push for @developer.

The [Virtual Refs '`NAME`'](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME) allows you to deny push for a given directory or file.

The [Drew Lesueur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95642/drew-lesueur) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925238/gitolite-permissoins-with-branches-and-folders#comment24439362_16925377):

```
  - master VREF/NAME/adirectory = user1
```

> It seems to not be doing an "and" condition but **an "or"** for us - `master VREF/NAME/adirectory = user1`
>   I ended up writing a custom VREF script for what I needed

I confirm that, in this case, only a custom VREF can match the OP's requirements, until gitolite 3.5 (and the introduction of '`and`'): see [sitaram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2353097/sitaram) (creator of gitolite)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16990110/6309).

Comment: Doesn't that restrict `user1` from creating a branch that includes `adirectory` ?

Comment: @DrewLeSueur no: the VREF "`NAME`" is about restricting a push by the names of dirs and files changed. `adirectory`, here, is a parameter of that virtual ref, not a branch name.

Comment: Right. `adirectory` is a directory name. If `user1` creates a new branch, and that branch includes the directory `adirectory` then `user1` cannot push it. (This is what we are running in to)

Comment: @DrewLeSueur that does sound like what you need, doesn't it?

Comment: I wanted user1's directory limitation to only apply to the master branch not other branches. (thank you for replying btw)

Comment: @DrewLeSueur I have edited the answer to address your requirement: `- master VREF/NAME/adirectory = user1`. You can specify *several* refexes, which allows you to deny push based on a VREF *and* on (`master`) branch name.

Comment: I seems to not be doing an "and" condition but an "or" for us `- master VREF/NAME/adirectory = user1` I ended up writing a custom VREF script for what I needed

Comment: @DrewLeSueur Right, I have included that caveat in the answer and emphasized the need for a custom VREF.

Answer (score 1):

As of v3.5, you can do this:

(1) add this line

```
'refex-expr',
```

somewhere [inside the ENABLE hash in the `.gitolite.rc` file](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L488-L506).

(2) use rules like this:

```
repo r1
    RW+ master                          =   user
    RW+                                 =   user
    RW+ VREF/NAME/Makefile              =   user
    -   master and VREF/NAME/Makefile   =   user
```

Documentation (including warnings!) is inside [`src/VREF/refex-expr`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/refex-expr#L18-L30).  There are some other neat examples in there.

Please note that I do not follow SO/SE/etc.; IMO the gitolite mailing list is the correct place for questions about gitolite.

However, someone pointed this one out to me, and since it referenced a very recent feature I thought I'd chip in.

-- 
sitaram