# Isolated permissions in GIT

Tags: git, github

I recently switched from SVN to Git and using gitlib for my code repository. But there is a quick question about it. I have a team those were experts in different modules in the project.
All I need is to isolate access of the folders in the projects to each individual.
For instance I have the project "Code31" which has the folders Design, HTML and PHP code.
I need designer to access only that folder and same with the other ones too..
Please throw some light on this scenario.

Thank you,
Kris

Comment: This is a very broad topic. As @uncletall's answer suggests, you could use a code review tool like Gerrit. Or a different Git server like Gitolite, which supports [fine-grained permissions](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html). Or...

Answer (score 1):

Using [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) (see "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)"), you can restrict access by folder, using the [VREF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309) `NAME`.

See "[advanced access control](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/aac.html)" for a concrete example.
I present one example also in "[gitolite permissoins with branches and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925377/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gerrit Code review](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/). It can give you a fine grained access control over your repository.