# Equivalent of Clearcase streams and views in Git?

Tags: git, clearcase

Continuing from my [earlier query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159030/equivalent-of-the-clearcase-baseline-and-clearcase-activities-in-git):

Trying to migrate to Git from Clearcase, but people keep asking these questions because they've designed their bureaucracy around Clearcase:
1. Is there an equivalent for Clearcase streams in Git? If not, how is it managed in Git?
2. What is the Git equivalent for a Clearcase view?
3. Clearcase has locks that the admin can use to protect files from unauthorized use. I understand Git depends on file/folder permissions, but in an Enterprise environment, would it really be possible to implement a secure environment for Git, with user specific permissions and firewall protection?

Comment: I have added some links to illustrate how gitolite works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1/ Is there an equivalent for ClearCase streams in Git? If not, how is it managed in Git?

No: a stream is an UCM metadata allowing you to declare components and share a common configuration among different UCM views for different users (all referring to the same stream)

The closest would be to add in a main Git repo [gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) to [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).
And you can make a [submodule follow a branch if you need to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309).

> 2/ What is the Git equivalent for a ClearCase view?

A **[`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)**: you get what is similar to a snapshot view, except you can change its configuration locally at any time (make new branches, switch or merge branches).

> 3/ ClearCase has locks that the admin can use to protect files from unauthorized use. I understand Git depends on file/folder permissions, but in an Enterprise environment, would it really be possible to implement a secure environment for Git, with user specific permissions and firewall protection?

Yes, on a blessed server for managing blessed repo.
Not on local cloned repo (where each developer does what he/she wants).

You can control who push/pull what on/from that blessed server, if you add an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/)** (See "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)" and **[its VREF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309)** in [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925377/6309)).

See more at "[Distributed Version Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685757/6309)".